# Update value in specific graph

Tags: sparql, jena

I would like to update values in a specific graph. When I call this query I get two triples in two different graphs:

```
select *
where {  
  GRAPH ?g {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER(?s = <http://mre.zcu.cz/id/2285692c932c88f8673a162ef7b5c997993da41cc>) .
    FILTER(?p = ds:diagDetail).
    FILTER(?o = 123)
  }
}
```

But when I try to update these values with this query nothing happened. The server returns success, but triples don't change. What am I doing wrong?

```
DELETE {?s ?p ?o}
INSERT {?s ?p 12345}
where {  
  GRAPH ?g {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER(?s = <http://mre.zcu.cz/id/2285692c932c88f8673a162ef7b5c997993da41cc>) .
    FILTER(?p = ds:diagDetail).
    FILTER(?o = 123)
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you use `GRAPH ?g { ... }` also in the `INSERT` and `DELETE` part then? Otherwise, those graphs won't be affected I think

Comment: otherwise it's just the default graph unless you don't specify the default graph with `WITH <g> ...` - not something you need in your case, so your current UPDATE statement just tries to delete from the default graph which does not contain the triple and adds a new triple to the default graph - which you can check with your SELECT query without specifying the `graph ?g`

Answer (score 0):

Try including the GRAPH keyword in the DELETE and INSERT statements.

```
DELETE {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p ?o   } }
INSERT {GRAPH ?g {?s ?p 12345} }
where {  
  GRAPH ?g {
    ?s ?p ?o .
    FILTER(?s = <http://mre.zcu.cz/id/2285692c932c88f8673a162ef7b5c997993da41cc>) .
    FILTER(?p = ds:diagDetail).
    FILTER(?o = 123)
  }
}
```

Otherwise it may be doing the changes in the "default graph", but not changing the triples in the actual graphs where they "live".